# How to change Angular Material mat-table width?

Tags: css, angular

I have an angular material mat-table such as:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="ds">
  ...
</mat-table>
```

I want to reduce the width of the displayed table.

Tried this in the .css but didn't work:

```
.mat-table {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Then went to the developer tools in Chrome browser and found the .css that actually changes the width just as I need.

Element:

```
<mat-card _ngcontent-vna-c44="" class="mat-mdc-card mdc-card">..</mat-card>
```

CSS:

```
mat-card[_ngcontent-vna-c44] {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 2em auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If I change that max-width to a different number(in Chrome dev tools), it changes the width exactly as I want.

But was not able to reference that element in the css.

Tried this but did not work:

```
.mat-card {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```